# Uncaught ReferenceError and CORS Policy Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I'm facing two issues in my web application:

Uncaught ReferenceError:

When clicking a button, I'm encountering "Uncaught ReferenceError: accessData is not defined," although the function is declared in my JavaScript code.

CORS Policy Error:

I'm making an XMLHttpRequest to 'http://localhost:8000/backend' from my front-end code.
The request is blocked due to a CORS policy issue:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/backend' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**server.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors'); // Add this line

const app = express();
const port = 8000;

app.use(cors()); // Enable CORS
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Function to check if it's lunch break
function accessDataDuringLunchBreak() {
    const currentHour = new Date().getHours();
    return currentHour >= 12 && currentHour < 13;
}

app.post('/backend', (req, res) => {
    const action = req.body.action;

    if (action === 'delete_data') {
        if (accessDataDuringLunchBreak()) {
            res.status(403).json({ error: 'Access denied during lunch break' });
        } else {
            // Implement your logic to delete data here
            res.json({ message: 'Data deleted successfully' });
        }
    } else {
        res.status(400).send('Invalid action');
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Data Access and Deletion</title>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="accessData()">Access Data</button><br><br>
<button onclick="deleteData()">Delete Data</button>

<script>
function accessData() {
    if (accessDataDuringLunchBreak()) {
        alert("Access denied during lunch break!");
    } else {
        // Perform AJAX request for data access (you can implement this as needed)
        alert("Data accessed successfully!");
    }
}

function deleteData() {
    if (accessDataDuringLunchBreak()) {
        alert("Access denied during lunch break!");
    } else {
        // Perform AJAX request for data deletion
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    alert(response.message);
                } else {
                    var error = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    alert(error.error);
                }
            }
        };

        xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8000/backend", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ action: 'delete_data' }));
    }
}

function accessDataDuringLunchBreak() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var currentHour = currentTime.getHours();

    // Assuming lunch break is between 12:00 PM and 1:00 PM
    return (currentHour >= 12 && currentHour < 13);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser is this happening in? I'm unable to reproduce your errors in Chrome.

Comment: Are you running your page from a `file://` URL? That would cause the CORS error.

Comment: 1) Can only be due to caching in my opinion. Clear your browser cache and try again. 2) As per @Pointy's comment and the duplicate